# Do I have to start a new game to play the Epsilon missions?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In the final main mission

> I opted to kill Michael, and now he seems to be dead for good.

Is there anyway I can still play the [Epsilon Program stranger missions](http://gta.wikia.com/Seeking_the_Truth) or do I have to start all over with a new game?

Comment: Please, please don't put massive spoilers in the question title...

Comment: @Fluttershy So sorry, didn't think about it at all, thanks

Comment: I am all over this tonight.  And @MathiasR.Jessen, you made the wrong choice ;)

Comment: @Archer Right? `C` was the obvious choice to make. No sacrifice and all the annoying bastards go *poof* instead :p

Comment: @Archer I most certainly did. On the other hand, RDR is still appealing after completing it 5 times, GTA5 will probably be the same. Off to a new game! :-)

Comment: Good man.  I'll be replaying it myself soon, just to try different styles of heist.  Damn being sensible next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still have a savegame from *before* you made the final choice, you can load that save to play the Epsilon missions without starting a new game.

If you no longer have such a save, i.e. you overwrote your only savegame with the endgame save, then you unfortunately have no other choice but to start a fresh new game.